# How do I animate the scene Rectangle?

Tags: python, animation, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qpropertyanimation

I am trying to move my QGraphicsScene rectangle using a animation to get the impression that it moves smoothly. But I don't know how to do it works. Could some one help me?  I would like to konow if its possible to animate a Qtransform instance. if it is, how can I do that?

Issues:

1 - How animate the translate function, which moves my scene rectangle. I want to animate it, because I want that it looks smooth.

2 - It's possible to animate a Qtransform instance?

here is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent) # this widget has no parent
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.setMinimumHeight(500)
        self.setMinimumWidth(500)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("move scene", self)  # this button is responsible to emit a signal to animate the
        # scene translation
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.do)  # connect to the animation
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()  # instantiate the scene
        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self)  # instantiate the view
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        hbox.addWidget(self.view)  # insert into the layout
        hbox.addWidget(self.button)  # insert into the layout
        self.r = self.view.mapToScene(self.view.viewport().rect()).boundingRect()# take the viewport bounding rectangle
        self.view.setSceneRect(self.r)  # define the viewport bounding rectangle as the initial scene rectangle
        self.scene.addEllipse(self.r, QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.darkRed), 10, join=QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin))
        # draw an ellipse in our scene
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.CrossPattern))  # set a grid patter to turn easier to
        # see the displacements of objects

    def translateSceneSmooth(self, ds: tuple) -> None:
        """
        ds = (dx, dy)
        :param ds: is the differential in x and y.
        :return: None
        """
        self.view.setSceneRect(self.view.sceneRect().translated(*ds)) # I want  that the animation pass a interpolation
        # of a tuple here: starting at (0, 0) and ending at (100, 100)
        # I don't know if this approach is correct.
        # Because maybe it will not  move 100 px.if I have a list of numbers in the form passing through the function:
        # [0, 10, 20, 50, 70, 100] maybe it'll move 0+10+20+50+70+100 = 250 px

    def do(self, duration=100):
        """
        I want the  scene rectangle to move smoothly
        """
        print('Starting animation')
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self._animation.setStartValue(0)
        self._animation.setEndValue(1000)
        self._animation.setDuration(duration)
        self._animation.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)
        self._animation.valueChanged.connect(self.translateSceneSmooth)
        print('Ending animation')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to animate the *scene rectangle*? If you want to move the ellipse, you should move that, not change the scene rectangle.

Comment: Your question is confusing, do you want to move the scene or do you want to move the items?

Comment: @eyllanesc  I want tomove the scene rectangle using an animation. To move it without animation I just have to 'update' the scene rectangle using this: self.view.setSceneRect(self.view.sceneRect().translated(dx, dy)) but with an animation I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @cap again, are you really sure you want to move the scene rectangle? From what we can see, there's no need for that and the ellipse item should be moved instead, can you clarify why do you need to move the scene?

Comment: @musicamante yes, yes sir. I'm sure. This is just an example, a simplification of my real program. And in my real program I have to translate the scene. And the only solution to translate the scene rectangle that I've found was using the method: 'translate (dx, dy)' . And now I have to make this translation looks smooth, And I don't have a clue how to do that.

Comment: @cap ok, the answer by eyllanesc should be enough, but keep in mind that if you constantly try to use the *current* scene rect to translate, you will not get the correct result, as the translation will result in a sum of the previous translation. Also, if you want to have different positions/speeds, you cannot just use a single animation, and you should consider using QParallelAnimation instead.

Comment: @musicamante why I will not get the correct result?

Comment: @cap the animation has progressive values; let's say you start at (0, 0) with 10 pixel steps: then the animation sends (10, 10), so you'll have the sceneRect at (0, 0) translated by (10, 10), moving it at (10, 10); the next step is (20, 20), but since you're using the *current* scene rect for the new position, which is at (10, 10), that step will move it to (10, 10) + (20, 20), resulting in (30, 30); the next animation step will be (30, 30), you already are at (30, 30), and then it will move to (60, 60), and so on.

Comment: @musicamante but this is what I wanted, very thank you for your concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move the sceneRect, generate an animation of the rectangle by calculating the starting and ending rectangles. On the other hand, by default, the pressed signal passes a boolean that overrides the default value of "duration", a possible solution is to use the pyqtSlot decorator to make the connection signature explicit:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(500, 500)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("move scene")
        # scene translation
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.do)
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(self.view)
        hbox.addWidget(self.button)

        self.r = self.view.mapToScene(self.view.viewport().rect()).boundingRect()
        self.view.setSceneRect(self.r)
        self.scene.addEllipse(
            self.r,
            QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.darkRed), 10, join=QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin),
        )
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.CrossPattern))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def do(self, duration=100):
        """
        I want the  scene rectangle to move smoothly
        """
        ds = QtCore.QPointF(100, 100)

        current_rect = self.view.sceneRect()
        next_rect = current_rect.translated(ds)
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self._animation.setStartValue(current_rect)
        self._animation.setEndValue(next_rect)
        self._animation.setDuration(duration)
        self._animation.valueChanged.connect(self.view.setSceneRect)
        self._animation.finished.connect(lambda: print("Ending animation"))
        self._animation.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)
        print("Starting animation")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```